# Save Selection of Pandas Dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have created a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

now I'm running a selection on it like this

```
print(df.iloc[2])
```

the Result is some subset of the dataframe.

The question is: how can I export/ save this Result to a CSV file?

merci in advance

A

Comment: @jezrael Sure ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `to_csv` function on the subset of `df`.

```py
df.iloc[2].to_csv('path/myfile.csv')
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for the comment. The behaviour of the parameters after `iloc` with one row is a bit different. `index=False` actually removes the column names and `headers=False` removes the index. I'll leave it to OP to decide how he wants it exactly.

Comment: thanks , @wouter, that works for me. the `index = false` is not needed since I want the index names saved as well. Thanks for the idea anyway. :thumbsup